# What is the advantage of creating an object with std::make_shared<my_class>() in C++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

In C++, you can create a class and an object of the class as following.

```
class my_class {
    public:
        my_class() {}
        void my_function() {}
}

int main() {
    my_class my_cls_obj;
    my_cls_obj.my_function();
}
```

But you can also create a class object of the type Shared Pointer as following.

```
class my_class : public std::enable_shared_from_this<my_class> {
    public:
        my_class() {}
        void my_function() {}
}

int main() {
    std::make_shared<my_class>()->my_function();

    // or

    std::shared_ptr<my_class> my_cls_shr_ptr = std::make_shared<my_class>();
    my_cls_shr_ptr->my_function();
}
```

What is the advantage of creating a class object of the type shared_ptr?

Comment: In your 1st example, the object is on the stack. Smart pointers (like `std::shared_ptr`) are replacement to using raw pointers allocated with `new` (i.e. in the heap, **not** on the stack).

Comment: The advantage of smart pointers over raw ones is the automatic memory management.

Comment: thats a moot comparison. If you are fine with creating the object on the stack then do that. `std::make_shared` comes into play when you are dynamically allocate it, and then the right comparison is vs using raw `new`

Comment: Your question is unclear. `std::shared_ptr<my_class>` is not `my_class` and does not function as `my_class`, it *points at* a separate object of type `my_class`.

Comment: Don't just think of the smart pointers (like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`) in terms of "auto-deleting pointers", but rather in terms of *ownership*. Who *own* a resource? No one (don't use pointers)? Only one owner at a time (use `std::unique_ptr`)? Or can ownership be shared (use `std::shared_ptr`)?

Comment: Use of std::shared_ptr assumes an understanding of pointers. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer

Comment: In your simple example, there is no fundamental advantage,   In more realistic and/or complicated examples (e.g. where an arbitrary number of individual objects needs to be dynamically created and may be referenced by multiple other objects) then using a `shared_ptr<>` offers an advantage (of managing each object) and `std::make_shared` reduces the need for the programmer to use `new` expressions directly - which tends to be error prone (e.g. increased risks that lifetime of some dynamically created objects are not managed correctly).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I wouldn't call local variables owned by "no one", they are owned by the function.

Answer (score 1):

There is none in the situation that you are showing and it would be a pessimization to use it.

`std::shared_ptr`/`std::make_shared` is meant to be used if you have multiple owners of the new object, meaning that you don't know in advance at which point in the program flow you want the object to be destroyed and that you want the new object to live as long as the union of the multiple owners' lifetimes.

If at all, you might want to use `std::unique_ptr`/`std::make_unique` in a situation like this if `my_class` is a very large class in order to make sure it is placed on the heap instead of the stack.

Comment: What is an owner of an object?

Comment: @OConnor The one responsible of its lifetime.

Comment: @OConnor If one object is an owner of another, it means that the former is responsible for (in the case of multiple owners conditionally) destroying the latter object (usually when the former object itself is destroyed but also potentially earlier).

Comment: In my case, my_class object should never be destroyed as long as the program is still running. It is a web service application. Should I create a normal object that will be stored on the stack or create a smart_ptr object that will be stored on the heap?

Comment: @OConnor If there can always only be one instance of the class consider whether it should be a class in the first place. In any case there is no need to have it on the heap. Either have it declared with automatic storage duration in `main` as you are showing or have it have static storage duration, either as a variable in `main` or as a singleton as global variable or something like a Meyer's singleton. Beware though that the order in which global variables are initialized is mostly unspecified.